# Having computer switch to guest account after a certain amount of time

Tags: login, login-screen, lock-screen, auto-login, xscreensaver

Instead of having the screensaver lock my computer is it possible to have it switch to the guest account instead.  I'm using ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Thanks